# soapui - match response value with request value

Tags: soapui, assertion

I have a SOAP Request like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://request.com" xmlns:dto="http://dto.com">  
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <req:requestInput>
      ......
      <dto:correlationId>${=UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase().substring(0, 16);}</dto:correlationId>
      ......
    </req:requestInput>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and SOAP response for the above request is like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://response.com" xmlns:dto="http://dto.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <res:responseOutput>
      ......
      <dto:correlationId>539A708FA1B44490</dto:correlationId>
      ......
    </res:responseOutput>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is my assertion
XPath Expression:

```
declare namespace env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace req="http://request.com";
declare namespace res="http://response.com";
declare namespace dto="http://dto.com";
//res:responseOutput/dto:correlationId/text()
```

Expected Value:

```
${Request#//req:requestInput/dto:correlationId/text()}
```

Error:

```
XPathContains comparison failed for path [
declare namespace env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace req="http://request.com"; 
declare namespace res="http://response.com";
declare namespace dto="http://dto.com";
//res:responseOutput/dto:correlationId/text()], expecting [6F37EA93D0454E67], actual was [539A708FA1B44490]
```

I want to check if the value passed in correlation id in SOAP request is returned in the response or not.
When this test case is executed, it had generated 539A708FA1B44490 in the SOAP request for correlation id.
but while doing assertion the script for correlationId is evaluated again which generates another id.
I just want to get the coorelation id in the payload sent in the request so that i can compare.

I have gone through the documents and searched for a solution and i did not.
I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When your assertion looks for the value `${Request#//req:requestInput/dto:correlationId/text()}` it will actually execute `${=UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase().substring(0, 16)}` **again**. Side note: the semicolon at the of the statement is not needed.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to have this code execute only once:

In the testcase setup script, run the following:

```
def uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase().substring(0, 16)
testCase.setPropertyValue('uuid', uuid)
```

Change **both** your SOAP Request and XPath Assertion to use: `${#TestCase#uuid}` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time, SiKing. I cannot keep the correlationId in the setup script as it is unique to each test step. Dont want to write script after each test step to update correlationId for next request.

Comment: Bummer! So in that case I would have to ask: is there any *benefit* in checking this `correlationId`?

Comment: Its like this. when correlationId is not present in the request, it is generated at the webservice. If it is present then it is returned. So i have to check if it is returning the correlationId or not when it is present.

Comment: If you have SoapUI-Pro, you could use a custom event http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/custom-event-handlers.html to generate this before each test step.